# Jasmine ignoring beforeEach inject

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

It seems like my Jasmine tests are ignoring my beforeEach function(The last one).  As you can see I have some console logs.  I basically get:

> DESCRIBE
>   CONTROLLER
>   undefined

INJECTING... is not being logged - Which is important since it is the part of the test responsible for mocking my service which is of course returning undefined because it skips over my beforeEach.

```
describe('Moment Controller', function() {

    var $scope, $controller, momentsService, $ionicContentBanner, core, components, $q, $ionicPopup;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('core'));
    beforeEach(module('components'));
    beforeEach(module('constants'));

    console.log("DESCRIBE");
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _momentsService_, _$ionicContentBanner_, _core_, _components_, _$q_, _$ionicPopup_) {
        console.log("INJECTING..."); //<--- IGNORED!
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        momentsService = _momentsService_;

        $ionicContentBanner = _$ionicContentBanner_;
        core = _core_;
        components = _components_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $ionicPopup = _$ionicPopup_;

        spyOn(momentsService, 'initializeView');

        $controller = _$controller_('MomentsController', {
            momentsService: momentsService, 
            $scope: $scope, 
            $ionicContentBanner: $ionicContentBanner,
            core: core,
            component: components,
            $q: $q,
            $ionicPopup: $ionicPopup
        });
    }));

    it('should initialize', function() { 
        console.log("CONTROLLER");
        console.log(momentsService);
    });

});
```

Anyone know whats going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you including `angular-mocks.js` in your test files?

Comment: Yes, I included that